# Detach a child window from its parent window by using another application

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I am a newbie to visual basic. I am trying to build an application that can control my other application.

So my first application has a child window inside the main window.

I want my second application able to control my first application. By pressing a button on my second application, it should make the child window in the first app to be a separate window. The window will be free to move outside of its original parent window. It should act as a separate window. The child window stays up even if the original parent window is minimized.

I kind get it working, but it's not as expected.

```
The problems I encounter now are:

     1. After the child window is detached, the child window still reminds in a background 
        frame looks like the background of its original parent window. I want the window to
        be on the desktop.
     2. After the child window is detached, the child window minimize with its main window. 
        I want the child window stay even if I minimize the main window.
```

The following is the code of my program:

Basically it is trying to get the handle of the main window through the window title and then get the handle of its child window and use the SetParent function to change its parent to the desktop, so it is shown on the desktop directly.

I know there might be other ways to do this and please let me know. It would be really helpful if you can be specific, since I mentioned I am new to visual basic. My code may look messy, sorry about that. :P Thank you everyone!

```
Option Explicit On

Public Class FormG
    Const GW_CHILD = 5
    Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
    Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndChild As Integer, ByVal hWndNewParent As Integer) As Integer
    Private Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim r As Int32, hChild As Long, desk As Long
        r = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Form1")
        hChild = GetWindow(r, GW_CHILD)
        desk = GetDesktopWindow()
        SetParent(hChild, desk)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Well even if the child window is detached from its original parent window, the parent process still has a handle to it and will control the window as if it's a child (since it is not expecting that it will be detached). The only way to overcome this is to frequently update the child window status (e.g. ´ShowWindow(..)´, ´MoveWindow(..)´ or functions like that) but this may lead to strange window behavior (e.g. window minimizes and pops up again and stuff like that)...

Comment: Applications *must not* mess with other application's window hierarchies.  In this case, since you control both applications, have one application send a message to the other to tell it to replace the child window with a separate window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall not try to re-attach a child to another window. While you **can** call `SetParent`, [it will be very, very hard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx) to do it right and solve all problems that raise from it. It's like if you were told that some person is now **your** parent. Could all involved people really behave as if it was true?

The solution to your problem would be having the first application have two windows sharing the same code: child window and non-child window. You will simply hide the one you don't need.

However, I have a feeling you're trying to achieve something that have a more direct and simple solution. You should describe what problem are you trying to solve with extracting a window.